# Split JSON into column in postgressql

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I have this simple table

```
create table orders 
(
  order_id int,
  address json
);
```

```
insert into orders(  order_id, address)
values
(1, '[{"purchase": "online", "address": {"state": "LA", "city": "Los Angeles", "order_create_date": "2022-12-01T14:37:48.222-06:00"}}]'),
(2, '[{"purchase": "instore", "address": {"state": "WA", "city": "Seattle", "order_create_date": "2022-12-01T14:37:48.222-06:00"}}]'),
(3, '[{"purchase": "online", "address": {"state": "GA", "city": "Atlanta", "order_create_date": "2022-12-01T14:37:48.222-06:00"}}]');
```

so far I was able to split purchase and address into two column

```
select
order_id,
(address::jsonb)->0->>'purchase' as purchasetype,
(address::jsonb)->0->>'address' as address
from orders;
```

```
1   online  {"city": "Los Angeles", "state": "LA", "order_create_date": "2022-12-01T14:37:48.222-06:00"}
2   instore {"city": "Seattle", "state": "WA", "order_create_date": "2022-12-01T14:37:48.222-06:00"}
3   online  {"city": "Atlanta", "state": "GA", "order_create_date": "2022-12-01T14:37:48.222-06:00"}
```

but I was wondering if anyone can help with how I can also split the address into 3 column(state, city, order_created_date)

I tried to subquery but won't work

I would like to see something like this

```
1 | online | Los Angeles | LA | 2022-12-01T14:37:48.222-06:00

2 | instore | Seattl | WA | 2022-12-01T14:37:48.222-06:00

3 | online | Atlanta | GA | 2022-12-01T14:37:48.222-06:00
```

Comment: your address is an array. What result do you expect if there multiple array elements?

Comment: expectation added ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
SELECT o.order_id
     , a->>'purchase' AS purchasetype
     , a->'address'->>'state' AS state
     , a->'address'->>'city' AS city
     , a->'address'->>'order_create_date' AS order_created_date
  FROM orders o
 CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_path_query(o.address, '$[*]') a
```

Result :

| order_id | purchasetype | state | city | order_created_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | online | LA | Los Angeles | 2022-12-01T14:37:48.222-06:00 |
| 2 | instore | WA | Seattle | 2022-12-01T14:37:48.222-06:00 |
| 3 | online | GA | Atlanta | 2022-12-01T14:37:48.222-06:00 |

see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/_8W0Th_4)